# Positioning a fixed element with limited height (max-height)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a fixed element to the bottom right corner of my webpage, which I have done with success.

[image]

I have also limited it's width with `max-width: 30%;` so in mobile devices it does not show the image too big. What I want to do now is to adjust the image by screen height as well. Is there anything else to figure this out except for Media Queries?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cornerImg">
   <a href="my-site-link-here">
      <img src="image/source.jpg" />
   </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cornerImg {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   max-width: 30%; /* Already working as expected */
   max-height: 30%; /* Adjusts the visible part of the image, but overflowing */
}
```

So I get the image resized on the screen, but it does not actually change the size of the image when it goes under the `max-height` condition. It just shows the top of the image and leaves the rest of the image invisible.

I know how to make this as Media Query, but I am seeking for a non-MQ solution here, if it is possible in any form. **Thank you in advance!**

**EDIT:** If any Media Query solutions come up, please provide some advice on that as well. It seems that even though I can adjust the height of the image in there by max-height, it still overflows the image out from the screen, so no luck on that side either.

Comment: have you tried `#cornerImg img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`? could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: it does not change height because you didn't specify how. `max-height:300px; height:30%;` will limit height to 300px or 30% (when 30% is less than 300px)

Comment: Tried it just now but no success. I can not necessarily provide a fiddle or the page itself, though it is public, but I'd have to ask the customer for permission. I will try to illustrate it by image, hold on.

Comment: @kecer no help from that one either. I updated my question by adding an image of how it actually goes when he screen height is too short and when it starts to shrink the image to fit in.

Comment: I would say go with this [this](http://codepen.io/kecer/pen/YwdXZe). `vh` means viewport height

Comment: Still overflowing, and when I raise the height a it more, the image does not stay at bottom anymore.

Comment: I am now open for Media Query solutions, as it seems that I get the exact same result from that method as well. Would be great if I could accomplish this in some way.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can try this

Comment: I would have to struggle with making it a clickable link to another site in this case, so I would rather keep it as an actual image and not go for background-image. Thank you for the answer though, appreciate it!

Comment: The .img-responsive class applies max-width: 100%, height: auto, and display:block to the image: Example <img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">

Comment: .responsive-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: This does not resize the image anywhere, and if I were to add the actual max-height property to my `#cornerImg`, the overflow kicks in again.